# how to identified android component are registered in manifist file?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

Is it possible to identified whether any activity/service are registered in manifist file or not?

Comment: If you have the source code, than doesn't opening and reading the manifest work?

Comment: thanks..but want to check before launch any activity/service.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PackageManager.getActivityInfo()` It will throw `PackageManager.NameNotFoundException` if it's not registered in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I'm not sure this will help you!!